# Finding non-zero function such that $f(2x)=f'(x)\cdot f''(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

I am thankful if someone can help me or show me the clue. As honestly as possible, I got stuck on this problem.

I need some help in finding a $f(x)\neq 0$ such that $$f(2x)=f'(x) \cdot f''(x),$$ where $f',f''$ are the first and second derivatives, respectively. It is not an ordinary differential equation.

My last try was to put $f(x)=ke^{ax}$, and then
$$ke^{2ax}=kae^{ax}\cdot ka^2e^{ax}.$$ Now by canceling $e^{ax}$, we have $$k=k^2a^3.$$ This shows $k=1,a=1$ and finally $f(x)=e^{x}$. But I want to solve the problem analytically.

Comment: @RamanujanXV. thanks but it's not the same idea... because of multiplication of f',f''

Comment: There are more solutions. For example:
$f(x) = \frac{4}{9}x^{3}$

$f'(x) = \frac{4}{3}x^{2}$

$f''(x) = \frac{8}{3}x$

Then $f(2x) = \frac{32}{9}x^{3} = \frac{4}{3}x^{2} \cdot \frac{8}{3}x = f'(x) \cdot f''(x)$. Anyway, I don't know a general solution

Comment: perhaps looking at periodic functions and working with $ \hat{f}'\left(n\right)\cdot\hat{f}''\left(n\right)=\hat{f}\left(2n\right)\Rightarrow-in^{3}\left(\hat{f}\left(n\right)\right)^{2}=\hat{f}\left(2n\right) $ might provide a simple solution by just guessing a few Fourier coefficients.

Comment: Another solution is $f_3(x)=\frac{\sinh (x\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2}}$. Found using Taylor expansion of $f(x)$. Using $a_0=1$, $a_1=1$ gives $f(x)=e^x$. Using $a_0=0$, $a_1=0$ gives $f(x)=\frac{4x^3}{9}$. Using $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$ gives $f_3(x)$.

Comment: How $k = k^2 a^3$ gives $k=1, a=1$? Since you're asking $k\ne 0$ this gives $k = 1/a^3$, and that gives the family of solutions $\frac{1}{a^3} e^{a x}$.

Comment: To my knowledge, this problem cannot be solved analytically without guessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I think one of the difficulties with this problem is that even when restricted to entire functions it is still super open. Basically, as long as you set the initial values for $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$ you get a new function. We shall investigate this equation for entire, complex functions.

**Case 1:** Let $f(0)=a\neq 0$ and $f'(0)=0$. Then we get

$$0=f(0)-f'(0)f''(0)=a-0f''(0)=a\neq 0$$

which is a contradiction.

**Case 2:** Let $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$. We can differentiate the given equation and solve for unknowns to find

$$f''(0)=0$$

$$f^{(3)}(0)=\frac{8}{3}\text{ or }f^{(3)}(0)=0$$

In fact, it won't matter which value $f^{(3)}(0)$ takes as the rest of the coefficients turn out to be $0$. To prove this, we will start with a complicated induction proof.

Claim: For $n\geq 4$, differentiating the given equation $n$ times gives us an equation of the form

$$0=2^n f^{(n)}(2x)-f'(x)f^{(n+2)}-(n+1)f''(x)f^{(n+1)}(x)$$

$$-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}f^{(3)}(x)f^{(n)}(x)+\sum_{i=4}^{\frac{n+5}{2}}c_if^{(i)}(x)f^{(n-i+3)}(x)$$

for odd $n$ and

$$0=2^n f^{(n)}(2x)-f'(x)f^{(n+2)}(x)-(n+1)f''(x)f^{(n+1)}(x)$$

$$-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}f^{(3)}(x)f^{(n)}(x)+\sum_{i=4}^{\frac{n+4}{2}}c_if^{(i)}(x)f^{(n-i+3)}(x)$$

for even $n$. Here, the coefficients $c_i$ are complex numbers and unimportant for the rest of the answer. This is easy to check for $n=4$ and $5$ by simply computation:

$$n=4: 0=16 f^{(4)}(2 x)-f^{(6)}(x) f'(x)-5 f^{(5)}(x) f''(x)-10 f^{(3)}(x) f^{(4)}(x)$$

$$n=5: 0=32 f^{(5)}(2 x)-10 f^{(4)}(x)^2-f^{(7)}(x) f'(x)-6 f^{(6)}(x) f''(x)-15 f^{(3)}(x) f^{(5)}(x)$$

Now, if $n$ is even, then we have

$$0=\frac{d}{dx}\left[2^n f^{(n)}(2x)-f'(x)f^{(n+2)}(x)-(n+1)f''(x)f^{(n+1)}(x)\right.$$

$$\left.-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}f^{(3)}(x)f^{(n)}(x)+\sum_{i=4}^{\frac{n+4}{2}}c_if^{(i)}(x)f^{(n-i+3)}(x)\right]$$

$$=2^{n+1} f^{(n+1)}(2x)-f'(x)f^{(n+3)}(x)-(n+2)f^{(3)}(x)f^{(n+1)}(x)$$

$$-\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}f^{(3)}(x)f^{(n+1)}(x)-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}f^{(4)}(x)f^{(n)}(x)+\frac{d}{dx}\left[\sum_{i=4}^{\frac{n+4}{2}}c_if^{(i)}(x)f^{(n-i+3)}(x)\right]$$

It is slightly tedious to show but it is also the case that

$$-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}f^{(4)}(x)f^{(n)}(x)+\frac{d}{dx}\left[\sum_{i=4}^{\frac{n+4}{2}}c_if^{(i)}(x)f^{(n-i+3)}(x)\right]=\sum_{i=4}^{\frac{n+5}{2}}c^{'}_if^{(i)}(x)f^{(n-i+3)}(x)$$

as desired. The same can be shown starting with odd $n$. Having this formula, we can now show that for $n\geq 4$, we must have $f^{(n)}(0)=0$. Since it is easy to show that $f^{(4)}(0)=f^{(5)}(0)=0$, assume that for some $n> 5$ we have $f^{(m)}(0)=0$ for all $4\leq m<n$. In conjunction with the fact that $f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=0$, this gives us that for even $n$ we have

$$0=2^n f^{(n)}(0)-f'(0)f^{(n+2)}(0)-(n+1)f''(0)f^{(n+1)}(0)$$

$$-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}f^{(3)}(0)f^{(n)}(0)+\sum_{i=4}^{\frac{n+4}{2}}c_if^{(i)}(x)f^{(n-i+3)}(0)$$

$$=2^n f^{(n)}(0)-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}f^{(3)}(0)f^{(n)}(0)=f^{(n)}(0)\left(2^n-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}f^{(3)}(0)\right)$$

Since $f^{(3)}(0)\in\left\{\frac{8}{3},0\right\}$, this implies

$$0=\frac{0}{\left(2^n-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}f^{(3)}(0)\right)}=f^{(n)}(0)$$

as desired. The logic is the same for odd $n$. In total, we have proved that if $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, then

$$f(x)\in\left\{0,\frac{4}{9}x^3\right\}$$

**Case 3:** This case is the most complicated and ambiguous of the three. Suppose that $f(0)=a$ and $f'(0)=b\neq 0$. At this point I don't really know where to go. It's not too bad to solve for as many of the generalized coefficients as you like. In fact, the first eight are

$$\left\{a,b,\frac{a}{b},\frac{2 b^3-a^2}{b^3},\frac{a \left(3 a^2-2 b^3\right)}{b^5},\frac{-15 a^4+12 a^2 b^3+4 b^6}{b^7},\frac{105 a^5-92 a^3 b^3-12 a b^6}{b^9},\frac{-945 a^6+822 a^4 b^3+116 a^2 b^6+8
   b^9}{b^{11}},\frac{10395 a^7-7686 a^5 b^3-2668 a^3 b^6-40 a b^9}{b^{13}},\frac{-135135 a^8+56280 a^6 b^3+74648 a^4 b^6+4192 a^2 b^9+16 b^{12}}{b^{15}},\frac{2027025 a^9+430920 a^7 b^3-2009736 a^5
   b^6-448096 a^3 b^9-112 a b^{12}}{b^{17}},...\right\}$$

If we only look at $(f(0),f'(0))=(a,b)$, there are some interesting functions which pop out;

$$\left(\frac{1}{c^3},\frac{1}{c^2}\right)=\frac{1}{c^3}e^{cx}$$

$$(-1,1)=-e^{-x}$$

$$\left(0,\frac{2}{c}\right)=\frac{2 \sinh (c x)}{c^3}$$

$$\left(0,-\frac{2}{c}\right)=-\frac{2 \sin \left(\sqrt{c} x\right)}{c^{3/2}}$$

which are all the functions previously discussed in answers and comments. For a complex example, we can use the exponential example we found above to get

$$\left(-1,e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\right)=-e^{-e^{\frac{2 \pi i }{3}} x}$$

Comment: Probably a typo. $\frac{2 \sinh(cx)}{c^2}$ is not a solution, $\frac{2\sinh(cx)}{c^3}$ is.

Comment: Whoops, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

*Too long for a comment.*

Assuming $f(x)$ is polynomial of degree $n$, we have $n = (n-1)+(n-2)$ or $n = 3$. Therefore we can look for $f$ in the following form:
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= a{x^3} + b{x^2} + cx + d \\ 
f'(x) &= 3a{x^2} + 2bx + c \\ 
f''(x) &= 6ax + 2b \end{align}$$
Then,
$$f(2x) = f'(x) \cdot f''(x) \implies \begin{cases}8a = 18a^2 \\ 4b = 18ab \\ 2c = 4b^2 + 6ac \\
d = 2bc\end{cases}$$
which gives the solutions $(0,0,0,0)$ or $(4/9,0,0,0)$. So the only polynomial solution is $$f(x) = \frac{4}{9}x^3$$

Answer (score 2):

As was observed in answers and comments, the only polynomial solution is $f(x)=\frac{4}{9}x^3$.

Your own work leads to the solutions $f(x) = \frac{1}{a^3}e^{a x}$.

Adding the initial conditions $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)\ne 0$ and assuming that $f$ is analytic, looking at the coefficients of the Taylor series we get $f(x) = \frac{2}{a^3} \sinh(a x)$

Without the initial conditions $f(0)=0$ and using the Taylor series it's clear that there's more solutions, but probably there's no simple formula for the coefficients of the series.

Without the assumption of the function been analytic, I have no idea how the problem could be attacked.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a solution and $a$ a positive number then $a^{-3}f(ax)$ is also a solution, as the examples so far illustrate.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $f'(x)\cdot{f''(x)}=\frac12(f'\cdot{f'})'(x)=f(2x),$ so that $(f'\cdot{f'})'(x)=2f(2x).$ Let $F$ be the antiderivative of $f$ with $F(0)=0.$ As such, let $F_2(x)=F(2x),$ so $F_2'(x)=2F'(2x)=2f(2x).$ Therefore, $f'(x)^2-f'(0)^2=F(2x).$ Perhaps the latter is more easily solvable for $f$ in terms of $F,$ and the equation can then latter be solved for $F$ when reformulated in terms of $F.$

Comment: such a nice idea. Thank you